# how to convert string variable from html input to int?

Tags: javascript

how do you properly convert a string value from an html input field?

i was tyring to do it with the number constructor method but its not working for some reason. Could someone please help ? thanks.

```
<script>
function myFunction ()

{

 num1 =  document.getElementById("text1").value;  
num2 = document.getElementById("text2").value;
num3 = document.getElementById("text3").value; 
num4 = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =num1*num2*num3/100;

 num1=Number(num3)

document.getElementById("resulet").innerHTML = num4+num3;
</script>
```

Comment: `num1 = parseInt(num1);`

Comment: [MDN also suggests specifying the radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), so `num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("text1").value, 10);`

Comment: Here num4 is still text .So num4+num3 will be internally equal to NaN+num3 which will be NaN.So use parseInt to convert them to integer  before adding

Answer (score 0):

Try to use parseInt something as follow, using second parameter is mandatory for base to avoid some problems. i.e. If a number start in "0" it will be parsed to hex base if it's not explicitly there.

```
num1 =  parseInt(document.getElementById("text1").value, 10);
```

More info here

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseInt()` - if you want to "support" older browsers, as second parameter you can set 10 as basis, so

```
num1 = parseInt(num1, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use parseInt()

```
num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("text1").value);  
num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("text2").value);
num3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("text3").value); 
num4 = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =num1*num2*num3/100;
```